# output folded block of text in yaml using ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

when I do message.to_yaml I am getting the following output

```
mainText: "<h3 class=\"right_column\">Mark</h3> ... "
```

but I want the output in the following format

```
mainText: |
     <h3 class="right_column">Mark</h3>  
     ...
```

How do you force ruby to use pipe to fold multiple lines of string.

I tried

```
message.to_yaml(:UseFold => true, :UseBlock => true)
```

but it is not working

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
irb(main):011:0> puts "Hi!\nIf your string has newlines...\nfolding is by default".to_yaml
--- |-
Hi!
If your string has newlines...
folding is by default
```

Comment: Thanks.

My string contained characters such as \xE2\xAC\x1C  which was messing with the yaml. How do you fix the line below?

    puts "</p><!--<h3 class=\"right_column_heading\">P Sales Representative \xE2\xAC\x1C Central   \n".to_yaml